# Not unzipping all files while using 7z in shell script

Tags: linux, powershell, 7zip

I am using below command

```
echo "A"|7z x -r -y /usr/sap/Silentinstall/commerce/commerce.7z.001
```

When I ran it from linux machine i.e. from cmd it works and it unzips all the files and folders.

But It it not extracting full files and folder when I am running it in shell script as below

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/sap/Silentinstall/commerce
echo "A"|7z x -r -y /usr/sap/Silentinstall/commerce/commerce.7z.001
chmod -R 777 /usr/sap/Silentinstall/*
```

Comment: I am running this shell script from power shell please suggest for the same.This seems weired behavior of 7z or anything is missing from my side.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: I wanna use #!/bin/sh only we followed this structure only.My issue is like it is not extracting all files when am running it from shell script and it is working from linux machine command promt. Please suggest ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of approaches i found below Solution,

cd /usr/sap/Silentinstall/commercedownloads
7z x /usr/sap/Silentinstall/commercedownloads/testcomm.7z.001 -o/usr/sap/Silentinstall/commercedownloads -aoa -r >>/usr/sap/Silentinstall/commercedownloads/log.txt
chmod -R 777 /usr/sap/*